# 0.0 rounded o 0 in wrapper - ApaceCXF REST

Tags: java, rest, cxf, zero, decimal-point

My application uses Apace CXF for exposing REST APIs and uses jackson for marshalling and unmarshalling.. In one of the endpoint, we return a wrapper which is a Map. Displaying decimal places is crucial for this application.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Output")
class Wrapper {
private Map<String, CountVO> data;

//constructor
//getter, setter

}

class CountVO {

private BigDecimal value;
//getter, setter, constructor

//updateMethod

public void updateValue(String userDecimalFormat){
switch(userDecimalFormat){
        case "1":
            this.value = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(1);
            break;
        case "2":
            this.value = BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(2);
            break;
        case "3":
            this.value= BigDecimal.ZERO.setScale(3);
            break;
}
}

}
```

Here, default value is set to 0 with decimal points based on certain configuration.

I have added tostring and loggers at relevant places in the code. What I could see is that, when the userDecimalFormat is 1 or 2 or 3, I get the desired output, viz count is set to 0.0, 0.00 or 0.000 resp and the same is printed in the logs.

But, the moment it is converted to json format, I get the desired output only when userDecimalFormat is 2,3. When it is 1, I get it as 0 and not as 0.0 in the resultant json. Here is the snippet.

```
{
   "Output": {
      "data": {
         "entry": [
            {
               "key": "1",
               "value": {
                  "count": 0
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "2",
               "value": {
                  "count": 0
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

In other cases, it is as follows.

```
{
   "Output": {
      "data": {
         "entry": [
            {
               "key": "1",
               "value": {
                  "count": "0.00"
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "2",
               "value": {
                  "count": "0.00"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

How do you suggest I resolve this issue?

Comment: where is the code that converts to json? Is that part of cxf?

Comment: Endpoint has @produces("application/json")

Comment: is there not java code in your rest method?  Please post that

Comment: Will do, in a while.

Comment: @OldProgrammer The endpoint has @Produces("application/json") and the wrapper has @XmlRootElement(name = "Output") annotated. There is no explicit pojo to json happening in the endpoint. I presume, the jaxb and jax-rs libraries take care of the conversion.